# How to fix overlapping text in Bootstrap 3 nested grid?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 3 nested grid in Ruby on Rails 4 application (as below) with the [bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

```
%div.row
    %div.col-md-3
        %div.row
            %div.col-md-3
                %h4 Number
            %div.col-md-3
                %h4 Name
            %div.col-md-3
                %h4 Title
            %div.col-md-3
                %h4 Overview
```

I end up getting overlapping text...e.g, if I have a long last name, it overlaps the text in the Title column for example.  The effect is similar to what is shown in the yellow box in the attached image.  How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: you need to increase your parent divs width from col-md-3 to col-md-4 and btw there will always be some names which will be bigger than the width of your element so it'll be better if you use ellipsis to truncate your name after some fixed width

Comment: Thanks Mandeep, no way to wrap the text?  The reason for having the parent div.col-md-3 is that I want 4 of those across the page (my understanding is that you need a sum of 12).

Comment: I mean you need to use col-md-4 on the parent div of your fields(second row in your code). We do have `word-wrap:break-word;` you can give it a try but i'll still suggest using ellipsis instead

Comment: "I mean you need to use col-md-4 on the parent div of your fields(second row in your code)" - That part I understood - but why does it need to be .md-4?  For instance could I set it to .md-2?

Comment: if it's col-md-4 then its children elements will have more width to occupy and hence more space for your name field, but then again some names will still be bigger than that so it's not a permanent solution to it. You either need to change your design or use ellipsis :)

Comment: also the word-wrap property will wrap text around but it also has a drawback as it'll move the whole word to next line, leaving void space at one end. Checkout [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap). Notice the space before long text

Comment: Example code you posted cannot produce result as in screenshot unless you changed some bootstrap variables or css classes.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel i think she has zoomed it to show text

Comment: @Mandeep this thing happening is impossible with bootstrap, unless it was messed with.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel yeah i know it shouldn't be like this unless some of the elements have width in px and not %

Comment: Thanks Mandeep I used the ellipsis approach.  Michal - The overlapping text in the yellow box of the sample image above shows what I'm experiencing with Bootstrap 3 - I didn't post an actual screenshot due to information sensitivity issues.